# how to connect HC sr04 on Raspberry with working code on Flask website?

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi3

I'm quite new and inexperienced in programming and this is my first job with Raspberry pi and Flask. I was given the task to calculate the distance and display the final data via Flask on the website. The script for calculating the distance works for me without a problem, I just don't know how to connect it to the website via Flask. Does anyone have any experience?
Here is my code.

````
import time
TRIG = 18
ECHO = 24
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
while True:
    GPIO.setup (TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup (ECHO, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output (TRIG, False)
    time.sleep (0.2)
    GPIO.output (TRIG, True)
    time.sleep (0.00001)
    GPIO.output (TRIG, False)
    while GPIO.input (ECHO) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time ()
    while GPIO.input (ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time ()
    pulse_duration = pulse_end-pulse_start
    distance = pulse_duration * 17150
    distance = round (distance, 2)
    print ("distance:", distance, "cm")```

I will be happy for any help.
````

Comment: Have you tried reading flask's documentation? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know what to do..

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do is create a local Flask app and display the distance on the screen:

```
from flask import * # Importing Flask.

app = Flask(__name__) # Initializing Flask app.

# You can add your calculating code as a function here, like 'def calc_distance():'
# You will have to return distance

@app.route('/') # Checks if app route is '/', basically just the domain name.
def show():
    distance = calc_distance()
    return distance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run() #This should run the app on localhost. An url will show up on the terminal. Click on the url to open the site.
```

The site will be blank with just the distance written.

This is very basic, you can do more like make an HTML file and serve it, download files, etc. I suggest you try looking at some tutorials as well as the documentation.

Here is a demonstration where I return 'Hello World!':

[image: Click Me]

Comment: I have already created local Flask app through this tutorial https://www.instructables.com/Python-WebServer-With-Flask-and-Raspberry-Pi/ but Im still really confused about it? Can we chat a little bit please?

Comment: Sorry, I only saw the message now. You have Discord?

Comment: Yeah, i do have discord, my name is nakirited#8712

Comment: Alright, I'll send you an invite, and we can talk there.